# Encrypt R File but still be able to run it

Tags: r

Is there a way to encrypt an R file? I wrote some algorithms for a customer but I don't want him to be able to read and copy what I did and keep it as a black box. The file, however, should run as normal using R or Rserve

Is there any way to do this? I found only information about how to encrypt Robjects, but not the file themselves

Comment: What you’re looking for is generally known as code obfuscation and the upshot is that, no, there’s no effective way of hiding source code from theft, and for R specifically there are no tools to even attempt it. As a trivial hurdle you can distribute the R code as a compiled R package. But this won’t *actually* prevent inspecting the source code, just make it slightly more work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protect/encrypt R package code for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283022/protect-encrypt-r-package-code-for-distribution)