# Obfuscate R code for docker image distribution

Tags: r, docker, security, dockerfile, obfuscation

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project where I've developed an R-based application that I intend to distribute via a Docker image. While I understand that Docker provides a layer of abstraction, I'm still concerned about the potential exposure of my R code to users who access the Docker container.

Objective: I'm looking for methods or tools that can help obfuscate my R code, making it more challenging for someone to reverse-engineer or understand the underlying logic.

Questions:

Are there any dedicated tools or R packages that can help with R code obfuscation?
How effective is byte compilation in protecting R code? Can compiled functions be easily decompiled?
Are there any best practices or recommendations for distributing R code in Docker images while ensuring the code remains protected?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905973/run-r-script-and-hide-the-actual-code-from-user, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264723/encrypt-r-file-but-still-be-able-to-run-it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562758/is-it-possible-to-compile-r-scripts-into-a-binary, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252065/sharing-r-functionality-with-multiple-users-without-exposing-code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283022/protect-encrypt-r-package-code-for-distribution.

Comment: In case you don't want to read @Marijn's very helpful links, the basic answer is "no".  If you use R, it's hard to do that.  If you need to do that don't use R.  (I'm sure it's not impossible but it's just not a recommended tool for that job).  I would consider keeping the R code and only making it available to your customer through a web-hosted shiny interface, for example.