# Is it possible to share a local R/Shiny app but prevent access to its source code?

Tags: r, shiny, code-access-security

Let's imagine you want to share a shiny app not remotely (i.e. without using shinyapps.io or a Shiny Server on the web - which may occur due to security issues), therefore you may need to "locally" share your app files (using `DesktopDeployR` for instance).

Is there a way to protect app source code from being read?

Comment: No, the R interpreter needs to access the R code. Please check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25283187/9841389).